# How do I convert a YUV (444) into a display on WPF, would prefer using DirectX somehow for hardware acceleration

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing, directx, yuv

I am working on displaying a Y4M movie to a screen. Parsing the file I can handle however I currently have a 2d byte array with the YUV values of the frame. Is there a built in hardware accelerated way or do I have to convert it to RGB and create a Bitmap? If anyone has a good website for a tutorial in DirectX in WPF it would be greatly appreciated as well. By the way this is in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YUV surfaces are likely special surfaces supported by a specific hardware vendor (IHV) FourCC.  You will need to find out from the IHV if they have a FourCC you can use and you can't rely on it working on other platforms.

There is a standard D3DFORMAT for 4:2:2 (D3DFMT_YUY2 or D3DFMT_UYVY) but there is no default one for 4:4:4.  I'm sure most IHVs do provide a FourCC for such rendering.

Its worth bearing in mind that if you know the FourCC of the incoming data then it may well be worth simply trying to create a surface with that FourCC directly.  If it works, you are ready to go :)  If not then you may be able to find an alternative that works or you may have to do some manual format conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm going to try it at some point over the holidays and will give you the rep then. Do you know of a good tutorial on how to use the D3DFORMAT?